# Java error: cannot cast to java.applet.Applet in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, processing

So here is really simple code that will not compile in Eclipse:

```
import processing.core.*;

public class MyPApplet extends PApplet {
}
```

I'm trying to run it as a Java Applet, but I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: MyPApplet cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
```

The problem is `PApplet` is a class from `processing` package, and it extends `java.applet.Applet`, and `MyPApplet` extends `PApplet`, but I still get this error. It makes no sense. Why can't `MyPApplet` be cast to `java.applet.Applet`?

Can someone please help?

Comment: are you really sure that `PApplet` extends `Applet`? Can you check it?

Comment: ClassCastException is a runtime error, and yet you say the code won't compile. So, which is it?

Comment: @malaguna I checked the documentation, and it extends Applet. I downloaded the previous version of the processing library: 2.2.1, and it worked just fine. Something must have changed when they made the new version 3.0.1, but there was no documented changes to PApplet.

Comment: @dsp_user Sorry, I'm used to C++ where if an error like that occurs, it fails to compile.

Comment: @Syd, it would be nice to have source code, but instead, you can debug and see what is the real type of `MyPApplet` on runtime. You can also compare the same against library 2.2.1 and 3.0.1

Comment: Add import to your MyPApplet.java file (e.g import package.subpackage.PApplet). For this to work, you need to add PApplet library (jar) to your class path. (in Eclipse , right click on your project and select Build Path->Configure Build Path and then under the Libraries tab add external library)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed processing 3 into swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101812/embed-processing-3-into-swing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like George said, `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet` as of Processing 3.

But instead of going back to an old version of Processing, I would recommend using the `runSketch()` function to run your sketch:

```
public class MyPapplet extends PApplet {

  public static void main(String... args){
    String[] pArgs = {"MyPapplet "};
    MyPapplet mp = new MyPapplet ();
    PApplet.runSketch(pArgs, mp);
  }

  public void settings() {
    size(200, 100);
  }
  public void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(0);
    ellipse(100, 50, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

If you really need access to the underlying native component, you have to write code that depends on what renderer you're using. Here's how you'd do it with the default renderer:

```
PSurfaceAWT awtSurface = (PSurfaceAWT)mp.surface;
PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas smoothCanvas = (PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas)awtSurface.getNative();
```

But the first approach should be good enough for most people, so try that first.

Answer (score 1):

In Processing 3.x PApplet no longer extends Applet:

> Applet is gone — Java's java.awt.Applet is no longer the base class used by PApplet, so any sketches that make use of Applet-specific methods (or assume that a PApplet is a Java AWT Component object) will need to be rewritten.

from github repo wiki page [Changes in 3.0](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0)

If you need the applet functionality, use an older version (2.2.1 or prior).

Answer (score 0):

The following is a template for Processing 3.x programs in Eclipse. However, you should run these as 'Java Application', rather than 'Java Applet':

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class P5Template extends PApplet {

    public void settings() {

        size(512, 200);
    }

    public void setup() {

    }

    public void draw() {

        background(0, 30, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PApplet.main(new String[] { P5Template.class.getName() });
    }
}
```